# The params doesn't give the right values in the ActionResult

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a process to import Excel-data. That works fine. But for starting the process I have to select some values. "Year from", "Year to" and the parameter isTest.

I want to change the range of the import-values. I have tried several solutions. But nothing works.
After changing the values and by clicking on the submit-button, I want to see the new values.

[image]

What do I have to change in the code?

This is the ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Importeren(int jaarVan, int jaarTm, bool isTest)
{
    //minValue = 1981; maxValue = 2004; isTest = true;
    _importProces.Start(jaarVan, jaarTm, isTest);
    return View();
}
```

This is the html-page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Importeren", "Home", new { jaarVan = ViewBag.JaarVan, jaarTm = ViewBag.JaarTm, isTest = ViewBag.IsTest }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xl-2">
            @Html.Label("Jaar vanaf:")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xl-2">
            @Html.Hidden("#JaarVan")
            <span id="lblJaarVan">@ViewBag.JaarVan</span><input type="range" id="jaarVan" value="@ViewBag.JaarVan" min="@ViewBag.MinValue" max="@ViewBag.MaxValue" step="1" 
                                                             onshow="showJaarVan(this.value)" oninput="showJaarVan(this.value)" onchange="showJaarVan(this.value)" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xl-2">
            @Html.Label("Jaar tot/met:")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xl-2">
            @Html.Hidden("#JaarTm")
            <span id="lblJaarTm">@ViewBag.JaarTm</span><input type="range" id="jaarTm" value="@ViewBag.JaarTm" min="@ViewBag.MinValue" max="@ViewBag.MaxValue" step="1" 
                                                           onshow="showJaarTm(this.value)" oninput="showJaarTm(this.value)" onchange="showJaarTm(this.value)" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xl-2">
            @Html.Label("Is test:")
            @Html.Hidden("#IsTest")
            <input type="checkbox" id="isTest" value="@ViewBag.IsTest" checked="@ViewBag.IsTest" />
        </div>
        @*<progress*@
        <p>&nbsp;<input class="text-primary" type="submit" value="Import Exceldata" name="Opslaan" /></p>
    </div>
}

<script>
    //$(document).ready(function () {
    //    $('#frmsubmit').submit(function () {

    //        var jaarVan = document.getElementById("#jaarVanRange").value;
    //        var jaarTm = document.getElementById("#jaarTmRange").value;
    //        var isTest = document.getElementById("#isTest").value;
    //    })
    //});

    function showJaarVan(newVal) {
        document.getElementById("lblJaarVan").innerHTML = newVal;
        ViewViewBag.JaarVan = newVal;
    }
    function showJaarTm(newVal) {
        document.getElementById("lblJaarTm").innerHTML = newVal;
        ViewViewBag.JaarTm = newVal;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the model binding for MVC form posts relies on the name attribute of your inputs, try adding names to your inputs to match the parameters in your action:

```
<input type="range" id="jaarTm" name="jaarTm" value="@ViewBag.JaarTm" min="@ViewBag.MinValue" max="@ViewBag.MaxValue" step="1"  onshow="showJaarTm(this.value)" oninput="showJaarTm(this.value)" onchange="showJaarTm(this.value)" />
```

I also don't think you need to include the route values object in the BeginForm() call because form data has higher precedence in model binding. That object is also evaluated before the post and hold the original years and not the new ones that you set in your range inputs.

Comment: Indeed I don't need the route values. I see. Thank you the year values (most important) works.